# Day vs Daily vs One-day vs Full day

Tags: word-choice

I want to convey the meaning of a certain activity that lasts no more than a full day. This could be a usage of such term:

"We sell *___* boat tours."

Which one of these alternatives is correct or fits best?

- Daily
- One-day
- Full day
- Day

Any help would be appreciated.

I am referring to activities that cannot be held overnight, eg. from 8pm to 6am, but can be done anytime inside a full day, be it in the morning or in the evening or from dawn to dusk.

Comment: If it is a 24 hour-trip,  you can sell *one-day boat tours*. If it's a daytime trip,  you can sell *all-day boat tours*

Comment: It's a trip that can last from a few to several hours, but never overnight. So for example it could be from 9am to 12am, or from 8pm to 10pm, or from 9am to 6pm, but never from, eg, 8pm to 6am

Comment: Then you can specify as *all-day* meaning *throughout the day time* or *all-night* meanin *throughout the night*. Or, *two-hour* or *three-hour trip* etc.

Answer (score -1):

We sell daily boat tours - we sell boat tours every day

We sell one-day boat tours - we sell boat ours that last one day

We sell full day boat tours - we sell boat tours that last a full day

We sell day boat tours - we sell boat tours that last a day

The differences between one-day, full day, and day are slight. The implication of full day is 24 hours - We sell 24 hour boat tours, whereas day is more likely to imply daylight hours - We sell dawn to dusk boat tours. One-day would make sense if you also offered 2-day and 3-day boat tours but as a term to distinguish a dawn to dusk tour from an afternoon tour doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: That last one reads strangely to me, like the tour is conducted on a particular type of boat called a "day boat". It could be improved by saying "We sell day-long boat tours".

Comment: @NuclearWang, indeed - even though day is a term representing a time-span is still doesn't quite sound correct. I'd guess that the ambiguous reference to either daylight hours or 24 hours introduces too much scope for interpretation. Day-long does imply daylight hours more than 24 hours.